# Using a set of numbers inside a database without creating a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a set of numbers and a table in a database with the `id` (primary key) and `text` (not null) columns. I would like to create a query that returns all the numbers in the set and the associated text from the table. Unfortunately not all numbers exist in the database's `id` column, so this won't work:

```
select id, text
from table
where id in (<set of numbers>)
```

For the non-existing ids the best would be to return `null` as the text from the query.

Is there a way to produce the desired output without first creating a temporary table from the set inside the database?

The database engine in use is a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP1 but I'd be interested in any solution with any database engine.

Comment: Why the desire to avoid creating a temp table?  That seems like the obvious best solution to me.

Comment: @jkohlhepp; it is not necessarily the best solution, for example oracle can generate sequential numbers with recursive query from dual that scales better then materialized version. don't have data for performance on MS SQL.

Comment: The exact reason for this request was given by Unreason - I would avoid creating farely large tables frequently.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are highly database specific

- mysql has no good way to do the above without temporary tables
- oracle can do the requested very efficiently with recursive queries (details [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques))
- ms sql can do it with recursive queries, but I don't know how efficiently

Check the linked article and see which of the queries MS SQL 2008 supports and how it performs on them.